# Can I use the R data.table join capability to select rows and perform some operation?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I'm not sure how to get the row indices resulting from the join of two data.tables.

To setup a simplified example, suppose dt is a data.table having column 'a' which is a letter from the alphabet, 'b' is some other piece of information.

I want to add a column 'c' and set it to either 'vowel' or 'consonant' depending on column 'a'.  I have another data table dtv which serves as a table of vowels.  Can I use the join capability of a data.table to efficiently perform this operation?

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table ( a = sample(letters, 25, replace = T), 
                   b = sample(50:100,   25, replace = F))
dtv <- data.table( vowel  = c( 'a','e','i','o','u') )
setkey(dt,a)
```

The next line of code gives me a data.table of rows with vowels

```
dt[dtv, nomatch=0]
```

But how do I grab the row indices so I can tag the row's as vowels or consonants?

```
dt[, c := 'consonant']
dt[{ `a` found in vowel list }, c := 'vowel']  
# I want to do this where column 'a' is a vowel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since V 1.9.4 `data.table` is optimized to use a binary join on `%in%` in case the data set is already keyed. So @Richards answer should have the same perfomance for the newest `data.table` versions (btw, `%in%` had a bug when used while `datatable.auto.index = TRUE`, so please make sure you have `data.table` v 1.9.6+ installed if you are going to use it)

Below is an illustration of `data.table` using a binary join when using the `%in%` function

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table ( a = sample(letters, 25, replace = T), 
                   b = sample(50:100,   25, replace = F))
dtv <- data.table( vowel  = c( 'a','e','i','o','u') )
setkey(dt, a)

options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)

dt[a %in% dtv$vowel]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs <~~~ binary join was triggered
#    a  b
# 1: i 87
# 2: o 84
# 3: o 62
# 4: u 77
```

---

Either way, you were almost there and you can easily modify `c` while joining

```
dt[, c := 'consonant']
dt[dtv, c := 'vowel']
```

Or if you want to avoid joining unnecessary columns from `dtv` (in case they are present) you could join only to the first column in `dtv`

```
dt[dtv$vowel, c := 'consonant']
```

Notice that I haven't use `.()` or `J()`. `data.table` will perform a binary join instead of row indexing by default in case `i`th element is not of type `integer` or `numeric`. This is matters if you, for example, would want to perform a binary join over column `b` (which is of type `integer`). Compare

```
setkey(dt, b)
dt[80:85]
#     a  b <~~~ binary join wan't triggered, instead an attempt to subset by rows 80:85 was made
# 1: NA NA
# 2: NA NA
# 3: NA NA
# 4: NA NA
# 5: NA NA
# 6: NA NA
```

And

```
dt[.(80:85)] # or dt[J(80:85)]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs <~~~ binary join was triggered
#     a  b
# 1:  x 80
# 2:  x 81
# 3: NA 82
# 4: NA 83
# 5:  o 84
# 6: NA 85
```

---

Another difference between the two methods is that `%in%` won't return unmatched instances, compare

```
setkey(dt, a)
dt[a %in% dtv$vowel]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs 
#    a  b
# 1: i 87
# 2: o 84
# 3: o 62
# 4: u 77
```

And

```
dt[dtv$vowel]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#    a  b
# 1: a NA <~~~ unmatched values returned
# 2: e NA <~~~ unmatched values returned
# 3: i 87
# 4: o 84
# 5: o 62
# 6: u 77
```

For this specific case it doesn't matter because the `:=` won't modify unmatched values, but you can use `nomatch = 0L` in other cases

```
dt[dtv$vowel, nomatch = 0L]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
#    a  b
# 1: i 87
# 2: o 84
# 3: o 62
# 4: u 77
```

---

Don't forget to set `options(datatable.verbose = FALSE)` if you don't want `data.table` to be so verbose.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need to use a merge/join. We can use `%in%`.

```
dt[, c := "consonant"]
dt[a %in% dtv$vowel, c := "vowel"]
```

or the same thing in one line -

```
dt[, c := "consonant"][a %in% dtv$vowel, c := "vowel"]
```

---

Alternatively (and better), we can do both of those steps in a single call with the following.

```
dt[, c := c("consonant", "vowel")[a %in% dtv$vowel + 1L]]
```